# Scoop selective export hdfs to mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a table 'test' in HDFS having columns ( id, name, city, salary ). I want to export (name, city ) to MySQL but when I use SQOOP command using --columns than MySQL columns got selected not test table columns in hdfs and data of id column in hdfs got transferred to name, name column of hdfs transferred to city column in MySQL.
*Is there any way to select a particular column from hdfs and pass it?*

Comment: You can specify a query with sqoop import  with the `--query` option. Just use `--query "SELECT name, city from db.table"`

Comment: here according to question i need to do export and we can't use --query with export as per my understanding

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use --hcatalog-table tablename which will take only desired column from hive table instead of --export-dir which will take a directory.